# Using Hibernate Criteria set Projection field as Foreign key column in the hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

How to set the projection filed as the foreign key reference in the hibernate criteria query.Example like,

```
 Criteria crt = s.createCriteria(UsersforGrades.class).createCriteria("id", "id1").createCriteria("id1.userId", "id2").add(Restrictions.eq("id2.userId", ue.getUserId()));
                ProjectionList proList = Projections.projectionList();
                proList.add(Projections.property("gradeId.gradeId"));
```

*Exception:*

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: gradeId of: com.treamis.entity.UserEntity
```

Answer (score 1):

Late answer although: (Came up with the same scenario)

In such case you need to create alias.

```
criteria.createAlias("gradeId", "gradeId");
criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("gradeId.gradeId"));
```